# Does the IronPDF free trial affect already built apps?

Tags: c#, ironpdf

I wanted to use the IronPDF library in an app for personal usage. They offer a free 30-day key, but I'm not sure if my PDFs will suddenly get watermarks in 30 days in case they validate the key somehow each time.

Comment: I... don't think a trial key would have the power to make watermarks appear in static files. Of course you could inspect the PDFs generated to see if there is some sort of dynamic magic that could make that happen.

Comment: @AKX, no, what I meant is if there is some kind of active validation in the library, it could start putting watermarks in newly-generated files despite the app being built while the trial was active.

Comment: Ah, well, _that's_ more likely, yes. Depending on how the licensing works, it'll probably either check online whether the key is still valid, or the expiry date will be encoded into the key itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/licensing/) is always free and open for development and testing.

If you need to test and share your project in a live environment with no watermarks, please [request a 30-day trial key](https://ironpdf.com/licensing/#trial-license), which can be easily applied directly in your code, as shown below:

```
IronPdf.License.LicenseKey = "IRONPDF-ZIVDERO-MY-TRIAL-LICENSE-KEY-EXPIRES.15.MAR.2022";
```

Other options for applying a key, (web.confg, appsettings.json, etc.) as K J mentioned can also be viewed here:
https://ironpdf.com/docs/license/license-keys/